# Set non-static objects params

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Have a nice day. How I can dynamically set values on objects creating? It's works:

```
        params: { country_id: '1'},
```

but if I try to set value from field, code not working:

```
params: { country_id: $("#country_id option:selected").val()}
```

I need this for setting function args

```
   $('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
        serviceUrl: 'ajax.php',
        params: { country_id: $("#country_id option:selected").val()},
    });
```

Comment: try to use `country_id: $("#country_id option:selected").val()`

Comment: Try spreading out the construction of your objects over `var`s and assignments, rather than using object literals.  That usually makes the step at which fields are calculated a little clearer.  If you don't see the problem then, you can add `console.log` calls to inspect the values you're assigning.

Comment: like this: `var foo = {}; foo.serviceUrl = 'ajax.php'; foo.params = {}; foo.params.country_id = $("#country_id option:selected").val(); $("#autocomplete").autocomplete(foo);`

Comment: also, in the docs for the jQuery UI autocomplete widget, I do not see the options `serviceUrl` or `params`, which is more likely your problem, assuming you're talking about the jQuery UI autocomplete widget.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the quotes.

```
params: { country_id: $("#country_id option:selected").val()},
```